# Using parallel strategies with monads

Tags: haskell, concurrency, parallel-processing, monads

I often see the usage and explanation of Haskell's parallel strategies connected to pure computations (for example `fib`). However, I do not often see it used with monadic constructions: is there a reasonable interpretation of the effect of `par` and related functions when applied to `ST s` or `IO` ? Would any speedup be gained from such a usage?

Comment: You want your IO actions to be performed in a certain order (e.g. first open the file, than read it, than close it). What do you want to parallelize there?

Comment: @helium: this mostly seems to come up either with mutable data or when using the FFI.

Comment: I've wondered this. I often open several large files (100 megs) and unzip them in parallel threads and then work with them after they are open. They are large enough to see a nice performance improvement but small enough I can hold them in memory. I've wondered how to do this in Haskel.

Comment: @Tim: Of course you can do it, you can just forkIO multiple threads to do it.

Comment: Time to learn about forkIO I suppose....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parallelism in the IO monad is more correctly called "Concurrency", and is supported by `forkIO` and friends in the `Control.Concurrent` module.

The difficulty with parallelising the ST monad is that ST is necessarily single-threaded - that's its purpose.  There is a lazy variant of the ST monad, `Control.Monad.ST.Lazy`, which in principle could support parallel evaluation, but I'm not aware of anyone having tried to do this.

There's a new monad for parallel evaluation called [Eval](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/3.1.0.1/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#t%3aEval), which can be found in recent versions of the [parallel package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel).  I recommend using the `Eval` monad with `rpar` and `rseq` instead of `par` and `pseq` these days, because it leads to more robust and readable code.  For example, the usual `fib` example can be written

```
fib n = if n < 2 then 1 else 
        runEval $ do
           x <- rpar (fib (n-1))
           y <- rseq (fib (n-2))
           return (x+y)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some situations where this makes sense, but in general you shouldn't do it.  Examine the following:

```
doPar =
  let a = unsafePerformIO $ someIOCalc 1
      b = unsafePerformIO $ someIOCalc 2
  in a `par` b `pseq` a+b
```

in `doPar`, a calculation for `a` is sparked, then the main thread evaluates `b`.  But, it's possible that after the main thread finishes the calculation of `b` it will begin to evaluate `a` as well.  Now you have two threads evaluating `a`, meaning that some of the IO actions will be performed twice (or possibly more).  But if one thread finishes evaluating `a`, the other will just drop what it's done so far.  In order for this to be safe, you need a few things to be true:

1. It's safe for the IO actions to be performed multiple times.
2. It's safe for only some of the IO actions to be performed (e.g. there's no cleanup)
3. The IO actions are free of any race conditions.  If one thread mutates some data when evaluating `a`, will the other thread also working on `a` behave sensibly?  Probably not.
4. Any foreign calls are re-entrant (you need this for concurrency in general of course)

If your `someIOCalc` looks like this

```
someIOCalc n = do
  prelaunchMissiles
  threadDelay n
  launchMissiles
```

it's absolutely not safe to use this with `par` and `unsafePerformIO`.

Now, is it ever worth it?  Maybe.  Sparks are cheap, even cheaper than threads, so in theory it should be a performance gain.  In practice, perhaps not so much.  Roman Leschinsky has a nice [blog post about this](http://unlines.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/sparking-imperatives/).

Personally, I've found it much simpler to reason about `forkIO`.